# Should we divide by 0 in limited question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I had a huge argument between me and my doctor, It was a limit question, and we had $e$ to the power $1$ divided by $x$ and the $x$ was approaching zero. The doctor ended the question by dividing by zero and saying that $e$ to an infinite power is also infinite, and because we have one divided by the above formula it will equal one and I said that this is a mistake.

**Here's how the doctor solved the question**

> $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x} + 1}{e^{-1/x} - 1} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\dfrac{e^{-1/x} + 1}{e^{-1/x}}}{\dfrac{e^{-1/x} - 1}{e^{-1/x}}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 + \dfrac{1}{e^{-1/x}}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{e^{-1/x}}}$$
>
> $$ = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 + \dfrac{1}{e^{-1/0}}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{e^{-1/0}}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 + \dfrac{1}{\infty}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{\infty}} = \fbox 1$$

I think that he is wrong and that we should not divide by zero, even if in this example the answer was right, but the steps were still wrong.

Comment: If $x$ were approaching $0$ through positive values (i.e., $x\to0+$) then the teacher's answer is correct but the calculation leading to it is not. If $x$  approaches $0$ through negative values, then the limit is not$1$ but $-1$. Finally, if $x$ oscillates between positive and negative while approaching $0$, then the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Andreas  But the OPs only objection was what he took to be division by zero, when working out a limit problem.  E.g., the user would object to $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{x^2}$ being evaluated as $\frac 1{0}$ with the limit being $\infty$.  There is no sign issue, or difference in this case whether $x\to 0^+$ or $x\to 0^-$.  If I understand correctly, the OP simply refused to accept the a train of thought that in evaluating limits, using the loose notation $\frac 10$ is appropriate.

Comment: @amWhy I agree that there are situations, like your $1/x^2$ example, where an informal division by $0$ is appropriate. And the OP shows no awareness of this fact. But this fact should only be used if one knows something about **when** it's safe to divide by $0$, and it appears that even the teacher doesn't (or didn't) know enough.

Comment: It is possible that your teacher did not kick you out because you objected; but rather because of the manner in which you objected.  We all need to work at civil interactions.  But we cannot know how either of you or your teacher behaved.  So it is not appropriate for any of us here to determine who behaved worse than the other.

Comment: I agree with you, @Andreas  But if you read the OPs post, that fact (the error in the teachers work) was lost on the OP.  Their utmost concern was the appearance of division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Do I think he should've kicked you out from the class? Well, that depends. Your concern is legitimate, but it is all about how you raised it. So I'm not going to comment further; this is something that would be entirely out of my field of expertise, and is not my place to comment on. Raise that concern with your professor.

---

Now, the core of your question is whether we should consider this valid:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} e^{1/x} = e^{1/0} = \infty$$

The answer is "no," from a technical/rigor sense - but from an intuition standpoint it makes sense. It's common to think of $1/x$ "blowing up to infinity" as $x$ becomes smaller, but it's still invalid to declare the limit as such because

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac 1 x = \infty \;\;\;\;\; \text{but} \;\;\;\;\; \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac 1 x = -\infty$$

Since the limits from each side are different, the limit as $x \to 0$ doesn't exist. More generally

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \text{ exists if and only if both } \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x), \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) \text{ do}$$

This is one of many reasons we don't even try to define $1/0 = \infty$. To claim $1/0 = \infty$ even in limits is only an appeal to intuition, often found in rudimentary calculus courses before proper rigor is introduced, and is by no means a hard rule.

So yes, your professor is wrong to do so, but not only is it an easy mistake to make, it's something that appeals to students' intuition. I suppose the jury is out as to whether appealing to intuition over rigor is a good idea or not, but I see why one might do that at least, probably even to avoid discussions like these. (Personally I'm in the camp of thinking it would be more important to deal with problems like these early on and handle things at least slightly more rigorously/properly, but I've yet to actually teach a class so ... who knows.)

---

In fact, **this particular problem needs to stand out in your mind, because your professor's technique even leads to the wrong answer.** This cements the point about $1/0 = \infty$ or $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x = \infty$ being an intuitive tool at best, and not proper rigor. If we graph your function, we see

[image]

This is ignoring some other errors your professor made. Namely, the third limit should be

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1+e^{1/x}}{1 - e^{1/x}}$$

Do the simplification yourself to see why (he just divides the numerator and denominator by $e^{-1/x}$, or, equivalently, multiplies both by $e^{1/x}$). It should be clear that this limit is $-1$, not $+1$.

But anyways, check the graph above. Notice how, depending on which direction your approach is from, the limit as $x \to 0$ doesn't even exist, same as it doesn't exist for $1/x$ as $x \to 0$!

Thus,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x} +1}{e^{-1/x} - 1}$$

doesn't even exist!

Why does this error arise? It is because your professor's idea uses

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac 1 x = \infty$$

with the sign on $0$ being important. After doing his trick, he is implicitly only doing a one-sided limit without realizing it. If he instead let it be $-\infty$ (which is equally as valid, i.e. not at all), he would get the limit to be $+1$ instead (ignoring the aforementioned other error).

Comment: Actually, the OP's only expressed objection was the appearance in the teacher's work of $\frac 1 0$.  They would have objected even if the teacher noted in some cases, it would be $\frac {-1}0$ and in other cases $\frac 10$.

Comment: The OP needs, most of all, to understand that such short-hand, while perhaps an abuse of notation, is common shorthand when evaluating limits.